# libksba install hangs up - rvm install 2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew

I'm trying to get ruby on rails set up on my work machine.
I'm trying to update ruby using rvm, but everytime I try, it gets hung up on the libksba install.

I've run brew doctor, brew update, chased many rabbit holes, and still no luck!

The error I get is:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libksba',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/myusernamehere/.rvm/log/1400009026_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_libksba.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

brew tap --repair seemingly does nothing, and brew doctor gives no errors!

Any ideas?
I've typed my fingers to bloody stumps trying to find a fix for this.

Comment: did you try `brew update` then `brew upgrade`

Comment: ran brew update and brew upgrade, then tried brew install libksba again and it failed again

Comment: Do you have xcode installed?